# How to convert Color to a list of RGB values in Dart & Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to be able to take a `Color` and convert it into a `List<int>` so like [0,255,255].

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<int> getRGB(Color c) {
  return [c.red, c.blue, c.green];
}
```

To use

```
Color c = Colors.red;
print(getRGB(c));
```